# Adding properties to next auth account when account is created

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I'm using Next Auth to handle authentication on my project but I'm having a small issue.
When you create a new account by signing in with a social provider like github or twitter, You get an object like this:

```
    _id:61dc91ff7581802bcba5d3b4
    name:Array
    email:"xxxxxxxxxxx@aol.com"
    image:"xxxxxxxxxxx.jpg"
    emailVerified:null
    __v:1
```

However because of the nature of the application I need the object to have a few more properties automatically generated when the account is created or it leads to problems where react can't render the page because it is trying to read a property that doesn't exist. For example the app can't render the page when its looking for `{session?.watchlists[i].watchlistName}`, if watchlists isn't an existing property.
This is what I need:

```
    _id:61dc91ff7581802bcba5d3b4
    name:Array
    email:"xxxxxxxxxx@aol.com"
    image:"xxxxxxxxxx.jpg"
    emailVerified:null
    followers:Array
    following:Array
    watchlists:Array
    __v:1
    status:""
```

The followers, following, and watchlists can be empty arrays, and status an empty string.

How do I go about adding these empty property fields ***when an account is created*** ?

Comment: Hey, Were you able to handle this scenario?